# Não consigo fazer o download de um arquivo por ActionLink mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Sei que o erro está na forma como eu estou interpretando a rotina. Tenho uma rotina para fazer download de uma arquivo anexado em uma table. Esse arquivo foi gerado pela minha aplicação(binário) e preciso agora gravar esse binário em um dir qualquer, ou seja, em minha table/grid há vários arquivos e preciso gravar o arquivo de ID tal. Bem, tentei várias formas e sei que um detalhe não estou conseguindo. Veja o que já fiz:
CONTROLLER:

```
public FileResult Download(int id)
        {
            int _arquivoId = id;
            var arquivos = oModelFiles.GetFileReport(id);

            string nomeArquivo = (from arquivo in arquivos
                                  where arquivo.ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO == _arquivoId
                                  select arquivo.BL_RELATORIO).First().ToString();//iSSO AQUI É TENTATIVA.

            string contentType = "application/pdf";
            return File(nomeArquivo, contentType, "report.pdf");
        }
```

Minha classe para pegar o arquivo

```
public class ModelFiles
    {
        public List<POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO> GetFileReport(int _Id_Solic_Relat)
        {
            List<POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO> lstFiles = new List<POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO>();
            //DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Arquivos"));
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Relatemp/");
            string arquivoCaminho = string.Empty;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                lstFiles.Add(new POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO()
                {
                    ID_RELATORIO = _Id_Solic_Relat,
                    //arquivoID = i + 1,
                    //arquivoNome = item.Name,
                    //FilePath = dirInfo.FullName + @"\" + item.Name
                });
                i = i + 1;
            }
            return lstFiles;
        }
    }
```

Minha view onde tem o botão Download

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.POC_RELATORIO.NM_RELATORIO)*@
            @Html.DisplayName("Nome do Relatório")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Relatório")
        </th>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID_USUARIO)*@
            @Html.DisplayName("Usuário")
        </th>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DT_SOLICITACAO)*@
            @Html.DisplayName("Data da Solicitação")
        </th>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO)*@
            @Html.DisplayName("Data do Agendamento")
        </th>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DT_GERACAO)*@
            @Html.DisplayName("Data da Geração do Relatório")
        </th>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BL_RELATORIO)*@
            @Html.DisplayName("Relatório")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.POC_RELATORIO.NM_RELATORIO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_USUARIO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DT_SOLICITACAO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DT_AGENDAMENTO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DT_GERACAO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BL_RELATORIO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { item.ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO, item.BL_RELATORIO })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Open", "", "")
        </td>
        @*<td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO })
        </td>*@
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Da forma que está, esse é o erro que está dando:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult
>   Download(Int32)' in 'Relatorio.Controllers.AppealReportController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Nome do parâmetro: parameters
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.ArgumentException: The parameters
>   dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable
>   type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult
>   Download(Int32)' in 'Relatorio.Controllers.AppealReportController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Nome do parâmetro: parameters
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual
>   solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da
>   exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de
>   exceção abaixo.
>
> Rastreamento de Pilha:

Comment: O que está errado no post para receber o downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está no caminho certo. Vamos apenas modificar algumas coisas:

Aqui:

```
    public FileResult Download(int id)
    {
        int _arquivoId = id;
        var arquivos = oModelFiles.GetFileReport(id);

        string nomeArquivo = (from arquivo in arquivos
                              where arquivo.ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO == _arquivoId
                              select arquivo.BL_RELATORIO).First().ToString();//iSSO AQUI É TENTATIVA.

        string contentType = "application/pdf";
        return File(nomeArquivo, contentType, "report.pdf");
    }
```

O erro diz que você não está passando `id` no endereço. Não sei como você chamou, mas acredito que tenha sido `http://endereco/Arquivos/Download`. Deveria ser `http://endereco/Arquivos/Download/5`, onde 5 é o id.

A segunda coisa é aqui:

```
return File(nomeArquivo, contentType, "report.pdf");
```

`nomeArquivo` precisa ser montado antes com [`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx), senão não funciona. Por exemplo:

```
nomeArquivo = Server.MapPath(nomeArquivo);
```

---

**EDIT**

Por comentário, você me disse que a URL usada é esta:

```
http://localhost:55839/AppealReport/Download?ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO=1&BL_RELATORIO=System.Byte%5B%5D
```

Mas repare que a assinatura da *Action* não possui estes parâmetros:

```
public FileResult Download(int id)
```

Se você precisa de mais parâmetros na *Action*, precisa declará-los. Por exemplo:

```
public FileResult Download(int SolicitanteId, bool ImprimirEmTela) { ... }
```

Os parâmetros da URL precisam ter exatamente os mesmos nomes passados como parâmetro:

```
http://localhost:55839/AppealReport/Download?SolicitanteId=1&ImprimirEmTela=true
```

Comment: Quando eu clico no botão download, a minha url fica assim: http://localhost:55839/AppealReport/Download?ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO=1&BL_RELATORIO=System.Byte%5B%5D, logo estou passando o parâmetro ou não?

Comment: Não está. Você está passando dois parâmetros que a *Action* sequer reconhece: `ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO` e `BL_RELATORIO`. Além disso, eles estão fora do padrão. Vou adequar minha resposta pra ver se fica mais claro.

Comment: Veja agora se fica melhor pra entender.

Comment: Era esse mesmo o problema e eu não sabia que deveria ter o mesmo nome. Por mim, bastasse eu ter um argumento com o mesmo tipo, claro na posição correta, que ele preencheria o argumento com o parâmetro correspondente e isso não dependeria do nome, mas mais uma que aprendi...